# get the list of users that have been worked inside a particular folder of a git project

Tags: git

I am working on a project made with a lot of modules. I think it is not important the language and/or the technology here. The main important stuff is that we need to know who have been worked inside `src/foo/bar` folder and who inside the `src/hello/world` folder.

I'll like to have the list of users. Is it possible with git?

Answer (score 0):

To list users who have worked on the project, you can use `shortlog`:

```
git shortlog -s
```

If you want to have this information but only for a specific directory inside the project:

```
git shortlog -s path/to/the/directory
```

Hope that helps